# Links in project

Tags: css, reactjs

I started to learn react js and created a sample, in which has header, footer with content but there is problem with my links when I add link to an image or text the cursor change to text and I cannot add pointer even by styling it with !important
I tried `NavLink` and `Link` from react but it don't work!
and I also thought there is problem with my `react-router-dom` but even it doesn't work with other url with even texts.

I couldn't find any other solution on Google either It already took me weeks searching.
there are two icons that they're supposed to work as Link button the note icon in the grid and arrow icon.

App.js is:

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
import Empty from './pages/Empty';
import First from './pages/First';
import Second from './pages/Second';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<First />} />
      <Route path="/Empty" element={<Empty />} />
      <Route path="/Second" element={<Second />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

First.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Navbar2 from '../components/Navbar2/Navbar2';
import Table from '../components/Table/Table';
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';

class First extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Navbar2 />
        <Table />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default First;
```

Table.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./Table.css";
import Red from './R.png';
import Yellow from './yellow-circle.png';
import Note from './notepad.jpeg';
import arrow from './arrow-transformed.png';
import magnifier from './magnifier.png';

class Table extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div className='Tablediv'>
        <h5>گزارش پروژه ها</h5>
        <a href='http://localhost:3000/Empty'><img src={arrow} className="arrow" alt="arrow" /></a>
        <a href='http://localhost:3000/Empty'><img src={magnifier} className="magnifier" alt="magnifier" /></a>
        <div className="table1">
          <div className='firstrow'>
            <span className='head'></span>
            <span className="head">کد نوسازی</span>
            <span className="head">کد ثبتی سازمان</span>
            <span className="head">پلاک ثبتی</span>
            <span className="head">بلوک</span>
            <span className="head">آدرس</span>
            <span className="head">مالک</span>
            <span className="head">کد ملی مالک</span>
            <span className="head">تلفن مالک</span>
            <span className="head">تاریخ ایجاد</span>
            <span className="head">نقش شما</span>
            <span className="head">وضعیت</span>
            <span className="head">عملیات</span>
          </div>
          <div className='row' id='back'>
            <span className='right'>
              <img src={Yellow} className="Yellow" alt="Yellow" />
            </span>
            <span></span>
            <span>97589</span>
            <span>2207/20.21</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>مجید حمیدی</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>1401/08/22</span>
            <span>اجراء مجری</span>
            <span className="waiting"><a>منتظر تکمیل سایرین</a></span>
            <span className="note">
              <img src={Note} className="Note" alt="Note" onClick={"/Second"} />
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className='row'>
            <span className='right'>
              <img src={Yellow} className="Yellow" alt="Yellow" />
            </span>
            <span></span>
            <span>222391</span>
            <span>232231124422</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>تست تستی</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>1401/05/08</span>
            <span>اجراء مجری</span>
            <span className="waiting"><a>منتظر تکمیل سایرین</a></span>
            <span className="note">
              <a href="http://localhost:3000/Second">
                <img src={Note} className="Note" alt="Note" />
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className='row' id='back'>
            <span className='right'>
              <img src={Yellow} className="Yellow" alt="Yellow" />
            </span>
            <span></span>
            <span>137835</span>
            <span>10613/318</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>محمدرضا سرخوش</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>1401/05/08</span>
            <span>اجراء مجری</span>
            <span className="waiting"><a>منتظر تکمیل شما</a></span>
            <span className="note">
              <a href="http://localhost:3000/Second">
                <img src={Note} className="Note" alt="Note" />
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>          
          <div className='row'>
            <span className='right'>
              <img src={Yellow} className="Yellow" alt="Yellow" />
            </span>
            <span></span>
            <span>202181</span>
            <span>124564189</span>
            <span></span>
            <span>قم-بلوارامین</span>
            <span>محمد محمدی</span>
            <span></span>
            <span>09121234567</span>
            <span>1399/09/20</span>
            <span>طراحی عمران</span>
            <span className="waiting"><a>منتظر تکمیل سایرین</a></span>
            <span className="note">
              <a href="http://localhost:3000/Second">
                <img src={Note} className="Note" alt="Note" />
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className='row' id='back'>
            <span className='right'>
              <img src={Yellow} className="Yellow" alt="Yellow" />
            </span>
            <span></span>
            <span>202181</span>
            <span>124564189</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>محمد محمدی</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>1399/04/39</span>
            <span>طراحی عمران</span>
            <span className="waiting"><a>منتظر تکمیل سایرین</a></span>
            <span className="note">
              <a href="http://localhost:3000/Second">
                <img src={Note} className="Note" alt="Note" />
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className='row'>
            <span className='right'>
              <img src={Red} className="Red" alt="Red" />
            </span>
            <span>2-5-6-3-1</span>
            <span>47585</span>
            <span>1864</span>
            <span>ساختمان</span>
            <span></span>
            <span>احمد و رعنا نوروزی و آقا پور</span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span>1397/03/08</span>
            <span>طراحی عمران</span>
            <span className="faild"><a>برگشت شده</a></span>
            <span className="note">
              <a href="http://localhost:3000/Second">
                <img src={Note} className="Note" alt="Note" />
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Table.css is:

```css
.Tablediv {
    direction: rtl;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
h5 {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.table1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 5fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr 4fr 2fr ;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-column: 12;
    grid-row: 7;
    height: 10%;
    column-gap: 0;
    row-gap: 0;
    cursor: text;
}
.Red {
    width: 13px ;
    height: 13px;
}
.Yellow {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}
.Note {
    height: 13px;
    width: 10px;
}

.head {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
}
.row span {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    position: relative;    
}
.table1 span::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    top: 15%;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(44,44,44,0.1);
}
.table1 .head::after {
    border-right:0;
}
.table1 .right::after {
    border-right:0;
}
.row {
    display: contents;
}
.firstrow {
    display: contents;
}
  
.row:hover span {
    background-color: #dbeaf486;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow {
    height: 13px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 143, 95, 0.164);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.magnifier {
    height: 11px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(101, 101, 101, 0.164);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.note {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.waiting a {
    background-color: rgba(255, 219, 151, 0.232);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: rgb(255, 166, 0);            
}
.faild a { 
    background-color: rgba(255, 151, 151, 0.232);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);  
}
```

Comment: Could it be to do with the `cursor: text;` rule you've set on your table?

Comment: no it's not. I remove it but still doesn't work.

Comment: I took the liberty to undo your addition of "I find the problem it was because of the content property in span::after". It is customary to post such additions either as a comment (so *here*), or if you have more details to share, to post it as an *Answer* to your own question. Or if the question is no longer relevant to you and did not receive an answer, then it is also very normal to just delete the question.

Comment: @PeterB thanks I'll write it down

Comment: If you face this problem or something same the reason is **display: contents;**